# Closed - How can I create a new input file when the first input file has a file selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file, upload

Edit:

I'll just use the attribute multiply, my problem is that is not supported in IE9 or earlier, but meh, that's the way it's going to be

Thanks everyone

---

I'm inserting data to a database, and for every entry I can have an unknown number of photos uploaded (maybe max 4) for that entry.

My question is: When I select a file in this form I want to make another input file appear to upload another file

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photos[]"><br>
<!-- ######## more data entries ######## -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I tried using jQuery like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fotos[]"><br>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script>
        $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
            $('#placeholder').html('<input type="file" name="fotos[]"><br>');
        });
    </script>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

but it only works for the first input

Is there another way to do this? i know there is multiply='multiply' but I'm not sure if it's well supported

Thanks in advance

PS: I don't care much what language to use as I know a little about everything, just go slowly on me :)

Comment: Have you considered using `multiple` attribute?

Comment: "i know there is multiply='multiply' but i'm not sure if it's well supported" i edited my comment, i forgot to put that

my priblem is that multiply is not supported for IE 9 or older

Comment: Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple. It returns an array, a simple array. You can get the `files` array using `prop` method: `$('input[type=file]').prop('files')`

Comment: thank you, i was struggling on how to get the array, cause `prin_r($_FILES['fotos'])` didn't work.